# Swift/CallKit. Is it possible to notify CallKit about accepting incoming call by custom UI?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I need to accept the call by tapping custom UI button.
From native push call screen system is notified by `CXProviderDelegate` method

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction)
```

[image: screenshot]
But how to notify CallKit with custom UI?

E.g. I can notify CallKit about ended call by method

```
reportCall(with UUID: UUID, endedAt dateEnded: Date?, reason endedReason: CXCallEndedReason)
```

Comment: If you want to use in-line formatting, surround code with backticks `like this` so that it's formatted correctly.

Comment: @AlBlue thanks. This is my first question on stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

If you still need to know how to manually notify the action from a custom UI, below you can find the solution.

In any case, let have it here for future references.

```swift
let answerAction: CXAnswerCallAction = CXAnswerCallAction(call: incomingCallUUID)
let transaction: CXTransaction = CXTransaction(action: answerAction)
            
callController.request(transaction) { error in
    if let error = error {
        NSLog("Error!!!")
    } else {
        NSLog("Success")
    }
}
```

note: callController type is `CXCallController`, and incomingCallUUID is the incoming call UUID reported by your CXProvider at `reportNewIncomingCall(with:)`